# How to properly route my app features in Front Door

Tags: azure-front-door

I have a SaaS application available at *.myapp.com, "*" being the customer name (eg: "microsoft.myapp.com" for Microsoft's account).

Currently this app is 1 mere app service set behind Front Door (Classic), but **we want to split it in 2, to separate the frontend and the API calls for performance reasons**.
So the plan is the following on Front Door :

[image]

The rules determine where the traffic goes through the URL :

- Starts with « /api/ » => forward to the API app service
- Everything else => forward to the frontend app service

[image]

The DNS has of course the following record :

```
*.myapp.com CNAME myFrontDoor.azurefd.net.
```

This setup generates a 404 error when trying to access existingcustomer.myapp.com.

[image]

From the error itself I understand that I must declare the domain name in the app service itself (which make very little sense to me because the domain name redirects to Front Door and Front Door is meant to redirect to a known Azure resource).

So I do it for the frontend app service and it works !

[image]

[image]

But when I go to the API app service to replicate the domain name setting, I get the following error :

[image]

*Validation failed. Hostname '*.myapp.com' conflicts with an already existing hostname. Conflicting app resource ID: /subscriptions/[guid]/resourceGroups/[rg]/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/app-myapp-frontend.*

I'm totally confused, the feature seams to force a setting which makes it unusable. What am I missing ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: you cannot have  the same domain "*.myapp.com" in both the App Service. You should insteadconsider having
 
frontend.myapp.com
api.myapp.com